# iPhone simulator doesn't quit previous version of app

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

Running the latest version of XCode, I run into the problem that when I try to start apps on the simulator multiple times. I have to quit the actual running app by clicking twice on the home button (multitasking task manager) in the simulator and quit the app. Otherwise a new 'build and run' simply opens the current running app in the simulator again (and in the same state as before). Where can I change that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you quit the simulator between builds, it should always re-install the app when you build and run.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Reset your iPhone simulator
Step 2. Press Cmd + Shift + K ( Clean all targets )
Step 3. Remove Build directory from your project source directory.
Step 4. Xcode Menu - Empty Cache
Step 5. Quit iPhone Simulator.
Step 6. Build your project & run.

**Edit :** You should quit simulator - before you click on Build & go option for that.

Check below given image to reset your iPhone simulator.

[alt text http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9449/screenshot20100710at100.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/9449/screenshot20100710at100.png)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. But I dont want to do all these steps everytime I want to try something on the simulator. In former times it was possible just to press the build and run button to quit the actual running app on the simulator and restart with the new one. Now, the old is still running and dont quit.

Comment: You should quit simulator - before you click on Build & go option for that.